# Opening and reading pdf file from devices internal storage android

Tags: android, pdf

I have no idea where to start, and can't find a decent, or at least understandable tutorial how to do it. Im still new to android (and coding in any matter) but i need to create and app that opens a pdf file (CV in my case) and reads phone number and email from it. Any ideas (tutorial links) how to do it? :)

Answer (score 0):

You could use iText library: http://itextpdf.com/

In FAQ, there's a question: "Can I extract/parse information from pdf ?"

http://support.itextpdf.com/node/27

Comment: @Šarūnas Shrooms Petkevičius, Is it useful ?